# Как сообщить об изменении DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть UserControl, в котором определена DependencyProperty PathObject. Она биндится и с помощью конвертера преобразуется в данные для Path:

```
<Path Data="{Binding Path=PathObject, ElementName=This, Converter={x:Static local:PathObjectConverter.Instance}}">
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при изменении значений в объекте PathObject, обновлялся Path. То есть как-то принудительно сообщить, что PathObject изменился.

Сейчас делаю так: храню дополнительный объект PathObject2, делаю биндинг вместо PathObject на него, обновляю его при изменении оригинального PathObject и сообщаю об этом через INPC (notify на PathObject не срабатывает):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PathObjectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PathObject", typeof(PathObject), typeof(PathObjectControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPathObjectChanged)));

    private static void OnPathObjectChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PathObjectControl c = o as PathObjectControl;
        if (c != null) c.OnMyPathObjectChanged();
    }

    public PathObject PathObject2 { get; set; }

    private void OnMyPathObjectChanged()
    {
        if (PathObject != null)
        {
            PathObject.PropertyChanged += PathObject_PropertyChanged;
            PathObject2.CopyFrom(PathObject);
            OnChanged("PathObject2");
        }
    }

    void PathObject_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PathObject2.CopyFrom(PathObject);
        OnChanged("PathObject2");
    }
```

Возможно ли обойтись без копии объекта PathObject и как-то сообщать о его изменении?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, вы делаете что-то неправильно.

Смотрите. Ваша DP есть *объект* типа `PathObject`. Сообщение об изменении срабатывает, когда подменяется *сам объект*, а не значения его свойств.

Что вы делаете, это подменяете *объект* при изменении *свойств*, таким образом, сообщения об изменении приходят. Для этого вам понадобился трюк с INPC.

Я бы посоветовал делать не так. Если вы хотите следить за изменением *свойств* объекта `PathObject`, то и ваш `Binding` должен быть к этим свойствам (поскольку вы привязываетесь к нескольким свойствам, вам, возможно, понадобится `MultiBinding`). Для этого вам нужно будет реализовать INPC для `PathObject` (что вы и так сделали). При этом само свойство `PathObject` по идее можно «понизить» из DP до обыкновенного свойства. (Но не поля!)

Альтернативно, если вы считаете, что при смене свойств объект `PathObject` логически меняется *как целое*, то сделайте его иммутабельным, и вместо изменения свойств создавайте новый объект и присваивайте его в DP `PathObject`.

---

Обычно ситуация следующая.

- Либо объект всегда меняется как целое, то есть при изменении подменяется *сам объект*. В этом случае объект кладут в DP и таким образом получают сообщения об изменении.
- Либо объект не подменяется, а меняются его *свойства*. Тогда объект должен реализовывать INPC (ну или сам быть DependencyObject'ом), и наблюдать надо не за ним, а за его свойствами.
- Либо объект является списком других объектов, которые приходят и уходят. Тогда этот объект должен реализовывать `INotifyCollectionChanged` (а не `INotifyPropertyChanged`), например, это может быть `ObservableCollection<T>`.
- В смешанной ситуации (которая должна встречаться очень редко!) вам придётся делать применять одновременно разные «рецепты». Например, если объект подменяется сам, и к тому же могут меняться его отдельные свойства, то он кладётся в DP, и реализовывает INPC. Привязка в этом случае обычно производится к «листовым» сущностям — свойствам.

---

«Насильное» отправление ложного сообщения об изменении DP — это костыль, не делайте так.